# Check my work: Find almost sure limit of product of uniform distributions

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, martingales, uniform-distribution, uniform-integrability

Suppose $\{\xi_n\}$ are i.i.d uniform random variables on $[0,1]$, and
$$\eta_n = 2^n\Pi_{i=1}^n\xi_i$$
then:

1. Show that $\{\eta_n\}$ is a martingale,
2. Find the almost sure limit of $\{\eta_n\}$
3. Determine if $\{\eta_n\}$ is uniformly integrable.

I have no problem with the first part, I also know that $-\log\xi_i$ follows exponential distribution with parameter $1$, so
$$\log(2^n\eta_n^{-1})\sim \text{Gamma}(n,1)$$
and consequently the pdf is given by
$$f_{\eta_n}(t)=\frac{(-\log(t)+n\log 2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!2^{-n}}$$
using Stirling's formula, for every fixed $t$ there is
\begin{align}
f_{\eta_n}(t)&=\frac{(-\log(t)+n\log 2)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!2^{-n}}\\
&=\frac{(n\log 2)^{n-1}(1-\frac{\log t/\log 2}{n})^{n-1}}{(n-1)!2^{-n}}\\
&\approx e^{\log t/\log 2}\sqrt{2\pi n}^{-1}(2^{-1}\cdot e\cdot \log 2)^{n-1}\left(\frac{n}{n-1}\right)^{n-1}\\
&\approx \sqrt{2\pi n}^{-1}e^{\log t/\log 2+1}(0.94)^{n-1}
\end{align}
which goes to zero as $n$ goes to $\infty$. So what is the almost sure limit? Is the martingale uniformly integrable?

Comment: Hint: use the equality $\frac{\log(\eta_n)}{n} = \log(2) + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \log(\xi_i)$

Comment: Consider the MGF of the Gamma(n,1) and take limits. You should find that the MGF goes to infinity. What can you deduce about the limit of $\log(2^n \eta_n^{-1})$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, taking the logarithm is a good idea. One has
$$
\log\eta_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(2\xi_i\right)
$$
hence
$$
\frac 1n\log \eta_n=\frac 1n\sum_{i=1}^n\log\left(2\xi_i\right)\to\mathbb E\left[\log(2\xi_1)\right]<0.
$$
Consequently, $\log\eta_n\to -\infty$ almost surely and $\eta_n\to 0$ almost surely.